# Stubbing: is it possible to use something like the opposite of __attribute__((weak))?

Tags: c, weak-references, stubbing

Let's assume the following C code:

**foo_bar_run.c**

```
#include "foo_bar_run.h"

int __attribute__((weak)) foo() 
{
    printf("foo\n");
}

int bar()
{
    printf("bar\n");
    foo();
}
```

**foo_bar_run.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int __attribute__((weak)) foo() ;
extern int bar();
```

**another_main.c**

```
#include "foo_bar_run.h"

int main(void)
{
    bar();
}
```

**bar_test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo_bar_run.h"

int foo()
{
    printf("stubbed foo\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    bar();
}
```

I want to have two separates programs:

**main_run**

```
gcc another_main.c foo_bar_run.c -o main_run && ./main_run
bar
foo
```

**main_test**

```
gcc bar_test.c foo_bar_run.c -o main_test && ./main_test 
bar
stubbed foo
```

Is there more elegant solution that would not include changing the foo_bar_run prototype? (it will stay `int foo()`)

Something like defining bar_test.c/foo() with `__attribute__(strong)`
or something not using any `__attribute__` keyword.

Comment: https://cppcodetips.wordpress.com/2020/08/18/mocking-a-function-in-c-using-wl-wrap-compiler-flag-in-gcc/

Comment: C or C++? You tagged this C yet use C++ syntax.

Comment: Anyway, it sounds like a plain "mocking" macro would work? In B.c do `#define foo another_foo`.

Comment: @Lundin - There's nothing in C++ that allows one to qualify an identifier by a **file name**. Is it that hard to comprehend rhetorical devices without jumping into language wars?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yes because if `A` and `B` are C++ classes or namespaces, it's a different question entirely.

Comment: @Lundin - It's a good thing they **aren't**.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I'm guessing I'm not the only person who places `class myclass` into `myclass.hpp`/`myclass.cpp`...

Comment: @Lundin - Plenty people having silly practices in languages they aren't too strong in isn't really an indicator of anything.

Comment: Please provide a [example]. `A::foo()` is clearly C++, so please tag your question as such, not C. -- If you are using GCC, did you consider to use the option `-wrap`? However, commonly this does not help if `bar()` calls `foo()`. Then you could resort to separate both methods in their own translation units.

Comment: I edited the question to avoid non intended debates ;)

Comment: @thebusybee the answer with ```-wrap``` does not work, it produces the same output for main_run and main_test

Comment: **As I said**, if `bar()` calls `foo()`, it is in the same translation unit, and the compiler resolves the reference directly. You cannot intercept it. Separate the functions.

Comment: you can write this answer so I can accept it

Comment: You have put `weak` in a header, all your symbols are weak.

Comment: This isn't C; more like GNU C with an ELF linkage model.

Comment: @Kaz my question is about C, any solution GNU or not GNU is welcomed

Comment: X-Y problem. Nothing like this exists as it is not needed. Simply your project structure is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The `__attribute__((weak))` is not part of the function type or storage class and need not appear in the header file declaration. It is a GNU C extension which has to do with weak symbols, which are a linkage concept. A symbol doesn't have to be declared weak at compile time to the places which use the symbol. Just the fact that it's an external symbol is enough. Weakness has to do with flexibility with how external references are resolved in the face of multiple definitions, when the program is linked together.

The problem you're trying to solve doesn't require weak symbols, because you are in control over all the symbol definitions and into how the program is divided into `.o` object files and which object files go into which executables. In your code and build structure, you can arrange for every program to be linked with a single definition of any `foo` or `bar` function.

Weak symbols help deal with certain issues in the deployment and maintenance of shared libraries. In particular, widely used platform libraries.